# Updating vertex buffers in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to learn DirectX and I want to move vertices around but I don't know how to update my buffers. This is what I have when I create a new buffer:

```
void GameObject::SetupBuffers(ID3D11Device* device, LPCWSTR textureName)
{
//Setup vertex buffer
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex::Basic32) * 24;
vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
vinitData.pSysMem = &vertices[0];
HR(device->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &vertexBuffer));

//Setup index buffer
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT)* 36;
ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
ibd.StructureByteStride = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
iinitData.pSysMem = &indices[0];
HR(device->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &indexBuffer));

HR(D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(device, textureName, 0, 0, &texture, 0));
```

}

If I were to then move the vertices around in vertices* how would I go about updating the buffer without calling this function again?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to map the vertex buffer to a pointer (using [`ID3D11DeviceContext::Map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457(v=vs.85).aspx). How do you want to change the vertex buffer? Moving an object around, rotating and other transformations are better done with an appropriate world matrix. This is way less data that needs to be transferred to the GPU.

Comment: I was trying to make a function that rotates the vertices of my model around a point. I should do that with a world matrix instead?

Comment: Yes, you should. Be aware that there is no rotation about a point. Only about an axis. Check out some of the [matrix helper methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixrotationaxis.aspx)